# EKS: can't see nodes and nodes are not join to the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I read all aws articles. I followed each one by one. But it didn't work any of them. Let me briefly summarize my situation. I created EKS automation with terraform. 1 vpc, 3 public subnets, 3 private subnets, 3 security group, 1 nat gateway(on public), and 2 autoscaled worker node groups. I checked all infra which created with terraform. There are no problem.

My main problem is that after the installation I can't see the nodes and nodes are not join to the cluster. I applied below steps but didn't worked. What should I do? By the way don't tag my question as a duplication I checked all similar questions on stackoverflow. My steps look true but does not work.

> kubectl get nodes

```
No resources found
```

Before checking node with above command.Firstly I applied below command for setting kubeconfig.

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name eks-DS7h --region us-east-1
```

Here my kubeconfig:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJfgzsfhadfzasdfrzsd.........
    server: https://0F97E579A.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:545153234644:cluster/eks-DS7h
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:545153234644:cluster/eks-DS7h
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:545153234644:cluster/eks-DS7h
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:545153234644:cluster/eks-DS7h
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:545153234644:cluster/eks-DS7h
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:545153234644:cluster/eks-DS7h
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eks-DS7h
      command: aws
```

After this I checked the nodes again but I still get no resource found. Than I try to edit aws-auth. Before the edit I check my user on the terminal where I triggered all terraform steps installation.

> aws sts get-caller-identity

```
{
    "UserId": "ASDFGSDFGDGSDGDFHSFDSDC",
    "Account": "545153234644",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::545153234644:user/white"
}
```

I took my user info and I added blank mapuser area in aws-auth. But still getting `No resources found`.

> kubectl get cm -n kube-system aws-auth

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapAccounts: |
    []
  mapRoles: |
    - "groups":
      - "system:bootstrappers"
      - "system:nodes"
      - "system:masters"
      "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::545153234644:role/eks-DS7h22060508195731770000000e"
      "username": "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
  mapUsers: "- \"userarn\": \"arn:aws:iam::545153234644:user/white\"\n  \"username\":
    \"white\"\n  \"groups\":\n  - \"system:masters\"\n  - \"system:nodes\"  \n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-05T08:20:02Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Terraform
    terraform.io/module: terraform-aws-modules.eks.aws
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "4976"
  uid: b12341-33ff-4f78-af0a-758f88
```

Oh also when I check EKS cluster on dashboard I see below warning too. I don't know is it relevant or not. I want to share it too maybe it will help.

[image]

Comment: Do the worker nodes exist in the ASG(s) that you created for EKS?

Comment: yea running and tagged like other services.

Comment: Can you show the worker config? Is it a managed or unmanaged node group? The warning means the user your using to access the console is not the creator of the cluster and/or not present in the aws-auth configmap.

Comment: @jordanm I'm not sure, here is my code can you check please. [link](https://github.com/Daggerphobia/EKS) When I triggered terraform I'm not seeing any node group under EKS.  Terraform creating instances with incremental names. If I can succesfully attach it will not a problem.

Comment: I see that you are specifying `worker_groups`, but I don't see that in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest). Looks like that should be `self_managed_node_groups` or `eks_managed_node_groups`. Your userdata script also contains undefined variables.

Comment: @jordanm maybe the problem is userdata. How should I change it?

Comment: Don't know, ive always used managed node groups. They don't have any extra cost so ive never had a reason not to.

Comment: You probably need to change the userdata script to a template so you can inject those values into the userdata.

Comment: do u know any good managed node groups repo example? I will also try in that way

Comment: @jordanm one more question do you know how can I open or create public ipv4 ip. I need to reach my app. https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks
I check the repo but I couldnt find it.

Comment: There are examples for managed node groups in the link you just provided. Public access to your cluster should be done via an ingress, through a load balancer created by aws-load-balancer-controller.

Comment: @jordanm Finally I managed to fix it. Like you said the problem is userdata undefined part. Please write an answer. I will mark it as anwer. By the way I have different problem right now. EKS working fine but I can't reach the app on browser. There are no ipv4 ip address. I don't want to add lb for cost problem. I want to expose on igw but when I checked the actual github repo which call main module from there. (also you mentioned above) They didn't define any igw in their code. So how can I add igw without broke the automation ffunctionality.

Comment: Internet gateway is for outgoing traffic, not incoming traffic. A load balancer is half the cost of the EKS control plane. If you use an ingress like nginx or traefik, you can have one load balancer service all workloads.

Comment: @jordanm can you copy the below code snippet and write as an answer please. I figured out because of you. Maybe someone will stuck in same point in the future. This will help them. When you post it I will delete this comment.
`MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
set -ex
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${CLUSTER_NAME} --b64-cluster-ca ${B64_CLUSTER_CA} --apiserver-endpoint ${API_SERVER_URL}

--==MYBOUNDARY==--\`

Comment: Try steps from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73868433/worker-node-group-doesnt-join-the-eks-cluster/74278536#74278536